# Balabolka doesn't show any of installed voices

Tags: windows-10, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices, tts

I'm using a x64 Windows 10 version, then I installed a balabolka TTS software along with IVONA voices and everything went well until the system did some updates then balabolka no longer recognized any voices at all (SAPI4, SAPI5, Microsoft Speech Platform)

I've installed an 32bit version of MicrosoftSpeechPlatformSDK and SpeechPlatformRuntime as mentioned in Balbolka Faqs pages but nothing changed.

The Windows Narrator App recognizes all my voices but still Balabolk doesn't. How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot of empty voices list shown by Balabolka Software]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but now Balaboka is working Superb in my PC.

With only TTS Balaboka won't work you need to intall screaming bee's MorphVOX Pro and then I gurantee you won't face any problem.

Link to MorphVOX pro(FREE) ::-https://screamingbee.com/Docs/MorphVOXPro/MorphDoc